Behaviour of modified Bessel function of first kind of order $-\frac12$, that is $I_{-\frac12}(x)$ for real $x\rightarrow0$
I have been trying to evaluate $I_{-\frac12}(x)$ around zero.
Now, I know for (10.2.4) of Abramowitz and Stegun that
\begin{equation}
I_{-\frac12}(x) = \frac{\cosh{x}}{\sqrt{\frac{x\pi}2}}
\end{equation}
However, when I evaluate these values in a small interval around 0, I get the function with values that go down and then go up. R code follows for $\{0.01,0.02,\ldots,0.99,1\}$.
cosh(x=1:100/100)/sqrt(1:100/100)/sqrt(pi/2)

  [1] 7.979245 5.643024 4.608662 3.992615 3.572709 3.263215 3.023112 2.829980
  [9] 2.670394 2.535759 2.420282 2.319898 2.231659 2.153368 2.083349 2.020298
 [17] 1.963185 1.911181 1.863612 1.819926 1.779660 1.742428 1.707904 1.675806
 [25] 1.645897 1.617969 1.591840 1.567355 1.544375 1.522777 1.502454 1.483309
 [33] 1.465255 1.448217 1.432124 1.416914 1.402530 1.388921 1.376040 1.363844
 [41] 1.352295 1.341357 1.330996 1.321183 1.311890 1.303092 1.294764 1.286884
 [49] 1.279432 1.272390 1.265739 1.259463 1.253546 1.247975 1.242736 1.237816
 [57] 1.233204 1.228888 1.224859 1.221106 1.217620 1.214393 1.211416 1.208682
 [65] 1.206184 1.203914 1.201866 1.200035 1.198414 1.196998 1.195781 1.194759
 [73] 1.193927 1.193280 1.192815 1.192527 1.192412 1.192468 1.192690 1.193075
 [81] 1.193620 1.194323 1.195179 1.196188 1.197345 1.198650 1.200098 1.201689
 [89] 1.203420 1.205289 1.207294 1.209434 1.211706 1.214109 1.216642 1.219303
 [97] 1.222091 1.225004 1.228041 1.231200

It seems a bit odd, but is this the expected behaviour?

Qualitatively you have a decreasing hyperbola-like function multiplying an increasing exponential-like function.  So yes there is a minimum somewhere near 0.  Find where the first derivative is 0, and that should be the minimum where you see a turn.

Aside from that, dividing by relatively small numbers on a finite precision machine is generally numerically bad.  You might be better off going with a series expansion of your function near 0, to get rid of that division by a small number.

@AndyWalls does that imply that the behaviour is correct? In that, it is true that the value goes to infinity as $x$ goes to zero, and goes down to that minimum, or is the error largely caused by the division by the small number? Thanks very much!

Wolframalpha.com shows that the global minimum is about $1.1924$ at approximately $x= 0.77170$.  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csqrt%7B2%2F%5Cpi%7D+x%5E%7B-1%2F2%7D+cosh%28x%29

And this function goes to infinity as $x\rightarrow\infty$?

Yes, it does.  $\cosh(x)$ dominates the behavior as $x$ goes to $\infty$.

Around zero,
$\cosh(x)$
is 1 so only the
denominator matters.
